# 20.04 Notification sounds not working

Tags: sound, 20.04, notification

Notifications don't play sound for me in Ubuntu 20.04.  I've tried it with chrome and notify-send from the command line.  No alert sounds.  Sounds are turned on in dconf editor (org/gnome/desktop/sound/event-sounds) and system sounds is at max volume in the sound settings, yet no sound for alerts.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu20.04 and I found that "System Sounds" has been changed.
Go to Settings -> Sound -> and change the volume level for "System Sounds"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `alsamixer`?

Open up Terminal, then type `alsamixer` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You will get an odd sort of panel with all your output and input devices listed across the bottom, and a vertical display of the sound levels.

Left and right arrows pan through the list of sound devices, and  up and down arrows increase or decrease the sound levels.

When you're dome making adjustments, just press Esc (the escape key) to exit.

Also read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alsamixer

Comment: This solution would make sense if *all* sounds were absent from the system but, based on the original question, it's *just* the notification sounds that are not working. How would adjusting settings in `alsamixer` resolve this for notifications if other audio playback works fine? 

Comment: You may have more sound devices than you realize.  Try elevating them all to see if it makes any difference.  It's possible that the assignment doesn't match your expected device.

Comment: Any luck with alsamixer?

Answer (score -1):

Go to System Settings -> Sound -> Sounds and click on the music notes - assign a sound file. It worked for me!